# Не могу реализовать полноценный ввод данных через поле EDIT

Tags: c++, winapi

Требуется сделать ввод данных через поле EDIT. Само поле ввода реализовал, остается как-то сохранить набранный в это поле текст. Голову уже "сломал", никак не получается!

Пытался сохранить текст в массив, а потом его же вывести через `MessageBox`. Выводится пустое окно.

Вот эта тщетная попытка:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    HWND hed;
    int len;
    TCHAR* buff;
    RECT screen_rect;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &screen_rect); // разрешение экрана
    int x1 = screen_rect.right / 2 - 300;
    int y1 = screen_rect.bottom / 2 - 75;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hed = CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT(""),
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_RIGHT, 50, 50, 500, 20,
        hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        len = GetWindowTextLength(hed) + 1;
        buff = new TCHAR[len];
        len = GetWindowText(hed, buff, len);
        buff[len] = 0;
        MessageBox(hWnd, buff, TEXT("text"), MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        delete[] buff;
        break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Надо полагать, что текст следует выводить ПОСЛЕ того, как он был набран.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выводите диалоговое окно с текстом `EDIT` сразу после того, как создали его.

Еще маленькая проблемка у вас в том, что когда вы пишите строчку `buff[len] = 0`, то вы выходите за пределы массива. Нужно писать `buff[len - 1] = 0`

Так же сразу скажу, что если вы внутри функции `WndProc` оставляете переменную `hed`, то нужно сделать её статичной.

Сохранение текста можно сделать разными способами. Например:

1. Выводим текст в статическую окно `STATIC`

   Будем устанавливать текст `STATIC` при изменении текста в `EDIT`, для этого нужно отлавливать соответственное сообщение `WM_COMMAND`

   Например вот так:

   ```
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE && LOWORD(wParam) == EDIT_ID) {
        len = GetWindowTextLength(hed) + 1;
        buff = new TCHAR[len];
        GetWindowText(hed, buff, len);
        buff[len - 1] = 0;
        SetWindowText(hStatic, buff);
        delete[] buff;
    }
   ```
2. А в `MessageBox` можно выводить при нажатии на кнопку, для этого так же нужно отлавливать событие нажатия кнопки.

   Например так:

   ```
    else if (LOWORD(wParam) == BUTTON_ID) {
        len = GetWindowTextLength(hed) + 1;
        buff = new TCHAR[len];
        GetWindowText(hed, buff, len);
        buff[len - 1] = 0;
        MessageBox(hWnd, buff, TEXT("text"), MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        delete[] buff;
    }
   ```

Вот пример всей функции `WndProc`:

```
#define EDIT_ID 1001
#define BUTTON_ID 1002
#define STATIC_ID 1003

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static HWND hed;
    static HWND hBtn;
    static HWND hStatic;
    int len;
    TCHAR* buff;
    RECT screen_rect;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &screen_rect); // разрешение экрана
    int x1 = screen_rect.right / 2 - 300;
    int y1 = screen_rect.bottom / 2 - 75;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hed = CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT(""),
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_RIGHT, 0, 50, 80, 20,
            hWnd, (HMENU)EDIT_ID, NULL, NULL);
        hBtn = CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Click"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
            0, 0, 80, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_ID, NULL, NULL);
        hStatic = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT(""), 
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_RIGHT, 0, 25, 80, 20,
            hWnd, (HMENU)STATIC_ID, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE && LOWORD(wParam) == EDIT_ID) {
            len = GetWindowTextLength(hed) + 1;
            buff = new TCHAR[len];
            GetWindowText(hed, buff, len);
            buff[len - 1] = 0;
            SetWindowText(hStatic, buff);
            delete[] buff;
        }
        else if (LOWORD(wParam) == BUTTON_ID) {
            len = GetWindowTextLength(hed) + 1;
            buff = new TCHAR[len];
            GetWindowText(hed, buff, len);
            buff[len - 1] = 0;
            MessageBox(hWnd, buff, TEXT("text"), MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            delete[] buff;
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
```

По итогу имеем `BUTTON`, `EDIT` и `STATIC`. Когда мы пишем, что-то в `EDIT`, то этот же текст выводится и в `STATIC`. А при нажатии на кнопку будет выводится текст из `EDIT`.

Comment: Хотелось еще спросить про то, что именно проверяет условие `HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE && LOWORD(wParam) == EDIT_ID` и `LOWORD(wParam) == BUTTON_ID`.

Comment: `HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE && LOWORD(wParam) == EDIT_ID` проверка на то, что произошло событие изменение текста && окно в котором изменился текст имеет `id = EDIT_ID` при создании мы `id` указываем окну. А `LOWORD(wParam) == BUTTON_ID` это просто проверка на то, что была нажата кнопка с `id = BUTTON_ID`

Comment: И еще один вопрос :)
Правильно ли я понимаю причину того, почему мы здесь делаем размер массива на один больше чем вводимый текст. А именно причина в том, что первый символ это **всегда** '\0'? 
      
`len = GetWindowTextLength(hed) + 1;`
          
 `buff = new TCHAR[len];`

Comment: `len = GetWindowTextLength(hed) + 1;` выделяется на 1 элемент больше, чтобы последнему элементу присвоить `\0`, что означает конец строки. Если вы выделяете память под `len` элементов, то индекс последнего символа `len - 1` и ему нужно присвоить как раз `\0`